# Mix values from two rows instead of union

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, union

I want to merge rows togheter instead of using for example union all. How can i do this? Thruu ref_id i know how to combinate.

Here is my example code (postgres):

```
create table dummy_table1(old_user varchar(20),new_user varchar(20),old_address text,new_address text,Ref_ID varchar(20));

create table dummy_table2(old_user varchar(20),new_user varchar(20),old_address text,new_address text,Ref_ID varchar(20));

insert into dummy_table1 values('dan',null,'Lincoln Street',null,'12bc');
insert into dummy_table1 values('peter',null,'Urban Street',null,'1b99');

insert into dummy_table2 values(null,'Steve',null,'Burban Road','1b99');
insert into dummy_table2 values(null,'barbara',null,'Ocean Drive','12bc');

select * from dummy_table1       
union all 
select * from dummy_table2
```

Output:

```
old_user      new_user     old_address    new_address  ref_id
dan           null         lincoln street null         12bc
peter         null         Urban street   null         1b99
null          steve        null           Burban road  1b99
null          barbara      null           Ocean Drive  12bc
```

My goal:

```
old_user      new_user     old_address    new_address  ref_id
dan           barbara      lincoln street Ocean Drive  12bc
peter         steve        Urban street   Burban road  1b99
```

Comment: Will there be more than one row per ref_id in each table? If not, why not just group by ref_id and take MIN() or MAX() of each column (since there's only one, it doesn't matter which you choose). And if there is more than one row per ref_id - how would you want to resolve that situation if it occurs?

Comment: Use full join based on ref_id and for each column Use ``coalesce(t1.old_user, t2.old_user)`` and so on.

Comment: Use coalesce() in every select column as per actual scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure there's a 1:1 match of the `REF_ID`s from each table you can use a `FULL JOIN`. For example:

```
select
  a.old_user,
  b.new_user,
  a.old_address,
  b.new_address,
  coalesce(a.Ref_ID, b.Ref_ID) as ref_id
from dummy_table1 a
full join dummy_table2 b on b.Ref_ID = a.Ref_ID
```